# How to use API's to manage Owncloud through simple Web or Android app

Tags: android, web, web-applications, raspberry-pi3, owncloud

I have set up Owncloud on Raspberry pi, so I would like to build a Web app or Android app to manage files such as downloads and uploads. I know I can manage all of that with Owncloud API,but I want something programmatic. 
Could anyone help me what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

The ownCloud team provided a tutorial, which can be found on their website:
https://doc.owncloud.org/server/9.0/developer_manual/app/tutorial.html

Should be easy enough to create a web app from there. You should look at some example apps at apps.owncloud.com too.